# SMTP send mail by codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I try to send mail using SMTP using codeigniter. But get following problem.
Even my credential is correct and work fine while i opened in gmail. After  that I got below message.

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [198.58.84.54]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
from: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
to: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
to: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
data: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. uo6sm2505144wjc.1 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
 User-Agent: CodeIgniter
 Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 11:07:54 +0000
 From: "Admin" <sflowask@gmail.com>
 Return-Path: <sflowask@gmail.com>
 To: pankaj.kumar.k@kindlebit.com
 Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Welcome_for_new_signup?=
 Reply-To: "sflowask@gmail.com" <sflowask@gmail.com>
 X-Sender: sflowask@gmail.com
 X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
 X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
 Message-ID: <55c9d78b01533@gmail.com>
 Mime-Version: 1.0


 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_55c9d78b01d05"

 This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
 Your email application may not support this format.
```

Comment: please post the code..

Answer (score 5):

You must change `$config['protocol'] = "smtp";` to `$config['protocol'] = "SMTP";`

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Why would this work? I see strtolower()s all over the Email class for the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,may it fixed your issue.It worked perfect for me.

```
$config = array();
$config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol']            = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
$config['smtp_port']           = "25";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->message = "Your Message";
$this->email->subject("Message Subject");
$this->email->from("user@gmail.com");
$this->email->to("admin@gmail.com");
$this->email->send();
```